# How to set an existing application in java to Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I already have a java application that uses servlets and JSP and it is perfectly running in localhost. I am confused about how to use this with app engine. I already have the Eclipse with GAE plugin. In what folder  or directory do I need to put my JSP files?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should at least first go through the documentation. There is a pretty easy and neat [getting started guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction). In there you'll find a sample way of structuring your app and getting started for the first time.

Also this:

> A Java App Engine application's access to the classes in the Java
>   standard library (the Java Runtime Environment, or JRE) is limited to
>   the following classes..... More [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist)

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I had already used these tutorials that you made reference. But there I am finding something to be created using maven. I already have an application created and don't know how to configure the directories, specially where to put the JSP.

Comment: @EvertondeCastro One possible way to go about it is to create a new GAE  skeleton project then copy all your existing files into that structure without changing the structure created by the plugin. You could as well take a look at this https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/existingprojects